# don't see result on sonar server web page by analyzing eclipse plugin

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

im trying to analyze a maven project via sonar on eclipse.Everything works fine,but I don't see anything on sonar server web interface.
I checked window>preferences>sonar>servers and it seems

**localhost:9000,**

**test connection:Successfully connected!**

but why doesnt seem result on web interface?

Comment: Because you haven't connected to your Sonar server. Add your sonar server details above and connect to it and run analysis on "Remote server"

Comment: thx for your answer but there is no section "run analys on Remote server".is there anything I overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read it in [the documentation of Sonar Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse), you must first make sure that your project has previously been analysed on Sonar (outside of Eclipse).

Comment: thats problem :) Im trying to use eclipse because of not analyzing on terminal.Keeping on figure whats wrong out.